# Email.js Works Locally, But not Once Deployed With React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, next.js, environment-variables

I have set up Email.js to make a contact page for a website built with Next.js. It works completely fine when run locally, but does not work when hosted. The form does not even reset when the submit button is clicked. I do this in the sendEmail function. The error handler does not trigger either in the .then block. I get this error in the browser console:

**Uncaught The user ID is required.** Visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin/integration

Here is how I send the emails:

```
export default function Book(props) {
  const form = useRef();
const [sentMessage, setSentMessage] = useState();
const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        props.SERVICE_ID,
        props.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID,
        form.current,
        props.USER_ID
      )
      .then(
        function (response) {
          setSentMessage("Message sent successfully!");
        },
        function (error) {
          setSentMessage("Message failed please email directly.");
        }
      );

    document.getElementById("form").reset();
  };

return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
          <form
            className={styles.form}
            ref={form}
            onSubmit={sendEmail}
            id="form"
          >
            <h3>Name (required):</h3>
            <input type="text" required={true} name="user_name"></input>
            <h3>Email (required):</h3>
            <input type="email" required={true} name="user_email"></input>
            <h3>Phone number (required):</h3>
            <input type="number" required={true} name="phone_number"></input>
            <h3>Message (optional):</h3>
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" value="Send">
              Submit
            </button>
            {sentMessage ? <p>{sentMessage}</p> : <p></p>}
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      USER_ID: process.env.USER_ID,
      EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID: process.env.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID,
      SERVICE_ID: process.env.SERVICE_ID,
    },
  };
}
```

I have a .env.local file with the template id, user id and service id that all work fine locally. I use next-env and dotenv-load in the next.config.js file like so:

```
dotenvLoad();

const withNextEnv = nextEnv();

module.exports = withNextEnv({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
});
```

I saw some problems online that people had with Gmail and remote email servers, so I switched the account to have no 2 factor authentication and use less secure apps as well. That had no effect.

Comment: First thing I'd try to do is console log these environment variables and see if they are alright.

Comment: I was reluctant to try that out on the live website because it would expose the variables, so I just set up a test site. You were right, I logged the variables on the test project and it came back as undefined. I then learned in searching around that you need to set up environment variables in the next.js dashboard. Thank you.

Comment: You did very well, great job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set up the environment variables in the next.js dashboard then rebuild the site so they take effect.